# Windows Batch: read and update file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am not sure, if the title is appropriate, so I am sorry for that.. :)

I have a script, that needs to keep some kind of statistics in a file.

The file looks like:

```
No of attempts: x
No of failed attempts: y
```

And that's just it. Now, I need to make a batch script, that will read those two numbers and updates them accordingly.

I have following piece of code, but it isn't working (surprise, surprise).

```
@echo off

set statfile=statfile.txt
set tmpfile=tmpfile.txt
set attempts=0
set fattempts=0

if exist %statfile% (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%statfile%) do (
        echo %%i > %tmpfile%
        if %attempts% equ 0 (
            for /f "tokens=4" %%j in (%tmpfile%) do set /a attempts=%%j+1
        ) else (
            for /f "tokens=5" %%k in (%tmpfile%) do set /a fattempts=%%k+1
        )
    )
)

echo No of attempts: %attempts% > %statfile%
echo No of failed attempts: %fattempts% >> %statfile%
```

I am really new to batch, so I am not sure if I even understand tokens correctly. And I know that logic of this script is... well, not good, I just don't know what bash offers and even though I looked, I wasn't able to find something actually helpful.

So thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I am more used to bash and today those two terms keep mixing together in my head... Thanks.

Comment: How do you propose to tell the batch whether you want to increment the fail or not? Are you expecting to increment the attempts each time you run the batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "statfile=q29529242.txt"
set "attempts="
set "fattempts="
FOR /f "tokens=4,5" %%a IN (%statfile%) DO (
 IF DEFINED attempts (SET /a fattempts=%%b) ELSE (SET /a attempts=%%a)
)
SET /a attempts+=1
REM IF (condition FOR false) SET /a fattempts+=1

echo No of attempts: %attempts% > %statfile%
echo No of failed attempts: %fattempts% >> %statfile%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q29529242.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Notes:

`set` statements always work on strings. The `/a` option interprets the value assigned as a formula and the result is assigned to the value.

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned. Assigning an empty value "deletes" the variable. Note that spaces **are** significant on **both** sides of the assignment.

The `for /f` tokens option interprets the line by using the `delims` delimiters, which default to space,comma,semicolon. The text line is regarded as a sequence of tokens separated by delimiter-**sequences**.

Hence, on the line

```
No of failed attempts: y
```

- No is token 1
- of is token 2
- failed is token 3
- attempts: is token 4
- y is token 5

Had you set 'delims=:' then

- No of failed attempts is token 1
- " y" (without the quotes) is token 2

(note that the delimiters themselves are **not** included)

You can select the tokens by number, separated by commas. The special token `*` means "everything in the line after the delimiter following the highest nominated token". The tokens are assigned lowest-selected to the metavariable (loop-control variable), and then in numerical order to each next alphabetical metavariable.

Note that within a "block statement" (a parenthesised series of statements) the value `%var%` is replaced by the **initial** value of the variable. There are ways to vary this behaviour. The `if defined` statement however uses the `current` value (it is either defined or not) as it varies within the loop.

Cnsequently, since `attempts` is cleared initially, after reading the first line, `attempts` is set to the `4`th token (x). On the second line, `attempts` has now been set, so `fattempts` is set to the `5`th token (y).

I used `/a` because the value will be numeric and that makes the assignment immune to spaces.

See

```
set /?
```

from the prompt for documentation on the C-like syntax of `set`

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF

set statfile=statfile.txt
REM I assume these two lines are just for demo?:
set attempts=0
set fattempts=0

if not exist %statfile% goto :error
REM read file (two lines):
<%statfile% (
  set /p att=
  set /p fatt=
)
REM remove anything before and including the colon and add delta:
set /a attn=%att:*:=% + %attempts%
set /a fattn=%fatt:*:=% + %fattempts%

REM write new file:
echo No of attempts: %attn% > %statfile%
echo No of failed attempts: %fattn% >> %statfile%
goto :eof
:error
echo Statfile not found
```

explanation of `set newvar=%var:*:=%`: the (first) colon tells the interpreter to do something with the variable, `*:=` is what has to be done: all from the beginning (`*`) until an colon `:` should be replaced (`=`) by - well nothing in this case.

As example, try this:

```
set "a=This is my string"
echo %a:*my=It's your%
```

Comment: Yep, just for demo. What does `:*:=` exactly mean? And this seems to be working, but only every other attempt - how is this possible? (instead of x.txt I use that %statfile%, because it should read and write in the same file - is it possible that this would be causing it?

Comment: I think, you missed my edit (a few seconds after the first answer). "every other attempt" sounds like a delayed expansion problem. Did you enclose (parts of) the code in parantheses (with an `if` or `for`?)

Comment: Yes, I actually did. So `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` should help? And thanks! :)

Comment: yes, that AND using `!var!` instead of `%var%` for the variables, you changed inside the same `(`block`)`